# HTML Data Entry Wizard, Fade and Slide Between Steps

Tags: jquery, html, wizard

I have a data entry form broken into multiple steps.  Each step is on its own div.  When filling out the form, I would like to have a nice transition between each step where the current step/div fades out, the height of the form is adjusted to the correct height for the next step/div and then the new step/div fades in.

This would work something like "[Lightbox](http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/)" but would not be in a modal popup.

Also similar to this [Sliding Form](http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/FancySlidingForm/) but there will only be "Next" and "Previous" buttons on the bottom and not a tab for each step.

Does a JavaScript library like this already exist, or is my best option to set each div to style="display: none;" and combine .slideDown() and .fadeIn()?

Comment: I feel compelled to mention that at 2430 rep I'd think you'd know to ask a clear question or someone will flame you.

Comment: I apologize, I've edited my original question - it will likely still be flagged, I'm just at a loss on this one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want with `Next` and `Previous` buttons [here](http://www.jquery-steps.com/Examples#basic-form) is very good demo.

And Here is the link of [GitHub](https://github.com/rstaib/jquery-steps) for above `jquery` plugin

Answer (score 3):

I have used [jQuery Steps](http://www.jquery-steps.com/) with a lot of success

It is extremely polished, provides validation per step, and it very customizable.